# How to restart game on same character?

Tags: borderlands-2

Ok so I'm replaying borderlands 2 on true vault hunter and I see that it says 'fast forward' after I do a couple missions. I click it (stupid decision) now I've fast forwarded the game when I wanted to re play it. Is there any way to restart my game on the same character?

I'm using a mac if it helps.

Comment: If you can play online, you could join a game at the start of True Vault Hunter mode and replay the missions with them.

Comment: aren't there an option to restart playtrough when you load a character ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to revert the fast forward on the same character. Unless you're willing to grind through Normal again, you're stuck.

You will have another opportunity to do those quests in Ultimate Vault Hunter Mode, though, if you have purchased any level-cap-increasing DLC.